Removing an old LVM filesystem and partitions
On an Ubuntu 20.04 virtual server, I had a huge 5.1TB /data mountpoint (LVM) that needed to be shrunk to a 3TB /data. Since the old /data was very complicated with 12 different partitions/PVs on four different hard disks, I decided to create a new /data (LVM with two 1.5TB virtual hard drives) and copy all the files to it, and then later remove the old four drives/partitions/LVM. I created completely new separate volume groups and logical volumes for the new /data.
So now I am at the removal part of old stuff, but it is a bit unclear what are exactly all the steps I need to take and in which order so that nothing is left behind and the OS doesn't get a hizzy fit. Does this sound about right (some questions within)?
sudo lvremove /dev/vg_data/lv_data
sudo vgdisplay

(check that the VG has no LVs anymore)
At this point, is it necessary to remove PVs from the VG with "vgreduce", if I am going to delete the whole VG anyway?
sudo vgremove vg_data

Removing the 12 physical volumes:
sudo pvremove /dev/sdb1
sudo pvremove /dev/sdb2
...
sudo pvremove /dev/sdd3
sudo pvremove /dev/sde1

Then remove partitions on the four hard disks with e.g fdisk, or is this necessary at all?
Will the OS complain and get confused if I remove a hard disk without removing partitions, or couldn't it care less?
After that I can safely remove the four old hard disk from the system, without leaving any remnants of them to the filesystem where the OS might get confused?
At this point I am not sure if I can remove the unused virtual hard disks from the VM (VMware) while the VM is running, but if not, I guess I will shut it down for awhile.
